# Renaming multiple files using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have following set of files

```
top_axi_256_wrapper_05.02.01.14.00_sample06.tgz
top_axi_128_wrapper_05.02.01.14.00_sample06.tgz
```

I want to replace `05.02.01.14.00` part with `05_02_01_14_00`. So the final output is the following renamed files

```
top_axi_256_wrapper_05_02_01_14_00_sample06.tgz
top_axi_128_wrapper_05_02_01_14_00_sample06.tgz
```

My directory may contain following type of file names too.

```
a72_a_0.0.0_0.00.04_ac_dc.tgz
```

Here , I wish to rename the file to

```
a53_1c_256K_a_0_0_0_0_00_04_ac_dc.tgz
```

How to do this?

Comment: The last example doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well, partly yes, I was trying to simply emphasize that I want to replace all the dots with dashes except for the extension one (.tgz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to replace a dot by an underscore except for the last one.

You can use bash's parameter expansion for that:

```
for file in * ; do
    replace_all=${file//./_}
    newname=${replace_all%_*}.${replace_all##*_}
    mv "$file" "$newname"
done
```

- `//./_` means *replace all dots by underscores*
- `%_*` means *remove everything after the last underscore*
- `##*_` means *remove everything up to the last underscore*

Or you can first save the extension, then remove it, replace all dots by underscores, and add the extension back. Left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Bash parameter expansion is new to me and I am liking it. Thanks a lot for introducing this to me.

Answer (score 1):

The `perl`-based `rename` utility can use any `perl` statements to rename files, not just the `s///` search-and-replace operator or the `y//` translation operator (just make sure you set `$_` to whatever you want the file to be renamed to).

From `man rename`:

> "rename" renames the filenames supplied according to the rule specified as the first argument.  The perlexpr argument is a Perl expression which is expected to modify the `$_` string in Perl for at least some of the filenames specified.  If a given filename is not modified by the expression, it will not be renamed.  If no filenames are given on the command line, filenames will be read via standard input.

For example:

```
rename 'my($b,$e) = m/^(.*)\.([^.]+)$/; $b =~ s/\./_/g; $_="$b.$e"' files
```

This splits the filenames into base name ($b) and extension ($e).  $b then has all periods (`.`) replaced with underscores.  Finally, `$_` is set to `"$b.$e"`.

Output (with the `-v` verbose option):

```
$ touch top_axi_256_wrapper_05.02.01.14.00_sample06.tgz \
    top_axi_128_wrapper_05.02.01.14.00_sample06.tgz \
    a72_a_0.0.0_0.00.04_ac_dc.tgz

$ rename -v 'my($b,$e) = m/^(.*)\.([^.]+)$/; $b =~ s/\./_/g; $_="$b.$e"' *
a72_a_0.0.0_0.00.04_ac_dc.tgz renamed as a72_a_0_0_0_0_00_04_ac_dc.tgz
top_axi_128_wrapper_05.02.01.14.00_sample06.tgz renamed as top_axi_128_wrapper_05_02_01_14_00_sample06.tgz
top_axi_256_wrapper_05.02.01.14.00_sample06.tgz renamed as top_axi_256_wrapper_05_02_01_14_00_sample06.tgz
```

BTW, use `-n` while testing your `rename` statements.  More from `man rename`:

> -n, -nono
>
> No action: print names of files to be renamed, but don't rename.

perl `rename` is available packaged for most distros (e.g. the `rename` package in Debian), or from https://metacpan.org/release/File-Rename