# Rename files add dashes after fourth and sixth characters

Tags: bash, terminal, regular-expression, rename

I have some files such as:

```
20150716_something-here
20150716_something-heretoo
20150716_something-hereaswell
```

They need to be renamed as

```
2015-07-16_something-here
2015-07-16_something-heretoo
2015-07-16_something-hereaswell
```

I tried using a [perl implementation](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/rename.rb) of the [`rename` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) (see my comment on the accepted answer) but I was not successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `perl` rename command (which is completely different to the `rename` command from `util-linux`):

```
rename -v 's/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1-$2-$3/' 2015*
```

(use `-n` rather than `-v` for a dry-run to test the command first).

This perl version of `rename` may be called `prename` or `file-rename` on your system.  It is far more capable and useful than the `util-linux` version of `rename`.  If you don't have it installed, you should install it.  If it isn't packaged for your distro, you can install from [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/release/File-Rename)

BTW, you can tell if you already have it installed by running `rename -V`.  If it produces output like this:

```
$ rename -V
Unknown option: V
Usage: rename [-v] [-n] [-f] perlexpr [filenames]
```

or this:

```
$ rename -V
/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 0.20
```

Then you have perl `rename` installed.  The former indicates an old version (which AFAIK lives on only on pre-jessie debian installs, included as part of the `perl` package).  The latter indicates the current version (now a separate package called `rename`).

Comment: wooops, I did not realize I was using a `perl` implementation of `rename`. Installed this package using homebrew via `brew install rename`, now doing `brew info rename` prompts `"Perl-powered file rename script"`

Comment: you might also be interested in this other answer i wrote about perl rename: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283606/7696

Answer (score 3):

Using bash's built-in substring expansion:

```
for f in 2015* ; do
  mv "$f" "${f::4}-${f:4:2}-${f:6}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1_\2_\3/' <file
```

Comment: How does this rename a *file*?

Comment: This one just format the text, it does not rename the file

Answer (score 2):

While `rename` is a very powerful tool, I normally prefer the simplicity of the [`mmv` (multiple move) utility](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/mmv.1.html):

```
mmv '????????_*' '#1#2#3#4-#5#6-#7#8_#9'
```

The `?` in the search pattern stands for a single character, the `*` for an arbitrarily long sequence of characters. In the replacement pattern, every `#<number>` stands for a corresponding `?` or `*` in the search pattern. In addition to `?` and `*`, `mmv` supports character ranges within brackets (like `[a-f]`).

(`mmv` will test for any conflicts in renaming before it starts work, so you do not risk losing files by overwriting.)

Answer (score 0):

On my distribution I have the `perl-rename` command, which can use a perl-style regex to bulk-rename files.  The `rename` command only accepts a pair of fixed strings for the rename.

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty not full solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
str=$1
yyyy=$(echo "$str" | awk -F '_' '{print $1}' | awk '{print substr($0, 1, 4)}')
mm=$(echo "$str" | awk -F '_' '{print $1}' | awk '{print substr($0, 5, 2)}')
dd=$(echo "$str" | awk -F '_' '{print $1}' | awk '{print substr($0, 7, 2)}')
new_str=$yyyy-$mm-$dd'_'`echo $str | awk -F'_' '{print $2}'`
echo $new_str
```

output:

```
$ bash script.sh '20150716_something-here'
2015-07-16_something-here
```